# React-ref update doesn't work without timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, settimeout, react-ref

I have spend the last couple of hours trying to programmatically set a value of a dynamically rendered HTML Select field in React. Even when I could log the element in the console using a ref I could not change it's value.
I have also tried to do this with basic JavaScript DOM manipulation aka document.getElementById() but alas, this produced the same result.

For the life of me I couldn't figure out what caused this. After much trail and error I managed to figure out my update statement did work when I placed it inside a timeout function, even with the timeout set to 0.

My question is if anyone can make this make sense to me since I have no clue why this would be. Also a work-around would be nice since this currently is not the cleanest code.

There is a list in which a location can be selected. When this occurs I want to update some select fields to show it's bound value as default.

I have the following useEffect hook which is supposed to set the default items of the selectLists based on the locationid which gets selected by the user:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const setDefaultSelectItems = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < GametypeItems.length; i++) {
        let defaultValue = 0;

        const defaultItem = GametypeItems[i].items.find(
          (item: GametypeItemItem) => {
            return item.locationid === SelectedRecordLocationid;
          }
        );

        if (defaultItem != null) defaultValue = defaultItem.itemid;

        // This is the code in question, the following does function as expected
        // (ItemSelectRefs.current as any)[i].value = defaultValue;
        // when the above line alone does not
        setTimeout(() => {
          (ItemSelectRefs.current as any)[i].value = defaultValue;
        }, 0);
      }
    };

    if (SelectedRecordLocationid != null) setDefaultSelectItems();
  }, [
    GametypeItems,
    SelectedRecordLocationid,
  ]);
```

The GametypeItems variable looks as follows:

```
{
   "gametypeid": "1",
   "name": "gametypename",
   "items": [
      {
         "itemid": 0,
         "locationid": 0,
         "item": "-"
      },
      {
         "itemid": "1",
         "locationid": "1",
         "item": "Item 1"
      },
      {
         "itemid": "2",
         "locationid": "2",
         "item": "Item 2"
      },
   ],
   ect...
},
```

This data gets rendered into a select list which sits in a cell of a react-table as such:

```
Cell: ({ row, index }: any) => {
   return (
      <select
         id={"item-select-" + row._original.gametypeid}
         className="form-select form-select-sm"
         disabled={selectedRecord == null}
         ref={(ref) => (ItemSelectRefs.current[index] = ref)}
      >
         {row.items.map((item: any) => {
            return (
               <option value={item.itemid} key={item.itemid}>
                  {item.item}
               </option>
            );
         })}
      </select>
   );
},


// This results in the following html
<select id="item-select-1" class="form-select form-select-sm">
   <option value="0">-</option>
   <option value="1">Item 1</option>
   <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I had the same kind of 'solution' to my problem. I was trying to auto focus an input in a child component with a ref in the useeffect. This didn't work until I added a timeout of 1ms...